Unexpected double free in single linked list
`I am trying to do a simple linked list. Everything works fine, but after the program calls ~List()
I am getting "double free in tcache2" and SIGABRT every time I run the program and debugger doesn't show anything meaningful to me. This list is only supposed to insert at the beginning and deleting on the end. It is just for Uni stuff. After reviewing similar question on stack I couldn't fix it by any means. Program is supposed to verify is a string is palindrome using stack and the list. Program works fine until the destructor is called.
INB4: I can't use std::list, because it is forbidden in my assignment
Any suggestion what can be wrong??
This is all of code where I am doing any memory allocation
template <typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    Node<T> *temp = head;
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::insert_element(T data)
{
    Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

template <typename T>
T List<T>::delete_element()
{
    T data;
    Node<T> *temp = head;
    if (head->next == nullptr)
    {
        data = head->data;
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
        return data;
    }
    while (temp->next->next != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    data = temp->next->data;
    delete temp->next;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    return data;
}

And here my program
    bool checkPalindrome(List<char> l, Stack<char> s, int string_len)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < string_len; i++)
        {
            if(l.delete_element()!=s.pop()) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        List<char> characters_l;
        Stack<char> characters_s;
        string input = "kajak";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            characters_l.insert_element(input[i]);
            characters_s.push(input[i]);
    
        }
        std::cout<<input<<" is "<<(checkPalindrome(characters_l, characters_s, input.length()) ? " " : "not ") <<"a palindrome"<<std::endl;
    
        return 0;
    }

I tried inspecting program by Valgrind but those messages are very unclear to me, I don't know why the element is free'd in the same place twice where I am calling delete once
==21949== Invalid read of size 8
==21949==    at 0x10AA83: List\<char\>::\~List() (list.hpp:36)
==21949==    by 0x10A727: main (lab1b.cpp:30)
==21949==  Address 0x4de0e18 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==21949==    at 0x484C91D: operator delete(void\*, unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:1101)
==21949==    by 0x10AAA3: List\<char\>::\~List() (list.hpp:37)
==21949==    by 0x10A6EF: main (lab1b.cpp:27)
==21949==
==21949== Invalid free() / delete / delete\[\] / realloc()
==21949==    at 0x484C91D: operator delete(void\*, unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:1101)
==21949==    by 0x10AAA3: List\<char\>::\~List() (list.hpp:37)
==21949==    by 0x10A727: main (lab1b.cpp:30)
==21949==  Address 0x4de0e10 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==21949==    at 0x484C91D: operator delete(void\*, unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:1101)
==21949==    by 0x10AAA3: List\<char\>::\~List() (list.hpp:37)
==21949==    by 0x10A6EF: main (lab1b.cpp:27)


Sounds like Rule of Three violation, but we cannot help without [mcve].

Valgrind output looks quite clear. It tells you that in line 36 you are trying to access some memory that was already freed in line 37. Cannot say more without https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , but you should be able to easily debug your program.

Make sure that there are no loops in your list.

A forward list is absolutely the wrong data structure for a palindrome checker.

The name delete_element sounds like it can delete an arbitrary node, but the reality is that it's supposed to delete the last node in the list. Tracking a tail pointer would simplify that significantly. Similarly for insert_element, it only inserts at the head of the list. Other names like push_front, pop_back, insert_front, or delete_back are a lot clearer.

And to my earlier comment, a forward list and a stack when all you need is the original std::string object is beyond silly. All you have to do is place a "pointer" (really just an index variable) on the first and last letters of the string object. As soon as the values are not equivalent, return false. If the pointers become equivalent (pointing to same character) or cross each other, return true. What's happening in this code is strange. Your list and stack are the same, but you make yourself traverse the forward list backwards (not how they're supposed to be used). It's not good.

If you absolutely have to use the list + stack (I would complain to the professor for an assignment whose use of these data structures makes sense), at least push to the back of the list and not the front. A tail pointer makes that simple, even for a singly-linked list. That way the list looks like the word, and the stack is reversed. Then, you don't even have to delete characters from the list. Just traverse it while popping off the stack.

I can't make this an answer as it doesn't solve your problem, but here's a demonstration of the simpler code I described, along with a variation of your attempt that adds to the list from the back, greatly simplifying the clunky solution: https://godbolt.org/z/j4YnWYhz9 My custom list only has the functions necessary for making this specific job possible and relatively straightforward to implement. There's probably a simpler way to implement the iterator, but I haven't been able to brush up on that.
